# Windows 7 update, results in "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: controlbrush" in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I'm having a little trouble here, I have a WPF application that have been running without any problems for several years. Now Microsoft have pushed out an update to windows 7, that results in the below error in the application.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'ControlBrush'  Key being added: 'ControlBrush'
```

This seems to suddenly be triggered by the following code

```
<TreeView.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Used for overriding default style in several windows.
I guess I can't get Microsoft to change their update, so I have to update my code to somehow handle this problem.
Do anybody have a suggestion for a work around, change of code, that could solve this problem ?

Just to clarify, the code haven't changed the last month and have been running fine, after two windows 7 pc's have been updated they both started showing this behavior.

### Update

It seems to be for the treeview component, the problem exists.

### Update 2

The update causing the issue is kb4520406 which is a .Net update (preview version)

Comment: Can you comment out that line where ever you have it, the error is because the key already exists and you are trying to give it the same name/add it again. Do you have this in a template etc.? What you can do is create another entry and change your windows to apply this new style. Can you show us the code with this in it?

Comment: Windows updates don't affect how code works. Post your code. That error complains that the item has already been added

Comment: BTW Windows 7 reaches End Of Life in January 2020 - that's 3 months away.

Comment: `Windows updates don't affect how code works` it can if your using a system resource that has changed.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ in this case any change to the *theme* would cause the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would agree, but if the theme hasn't changed, what do you suggest is the problem?

Comment: If you know what updates were installed, can you share the Microsoft KB update id/s?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ oops - I misunderstood what `ControlBrushKey` returns and an update *can't* cause that error - the error says that `ControlBrush` is already added to the resources. If you check the code `[ControlBrushKey](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/SystemColors.cs,1283) returns a well-known key based on [an enum](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/SystemResourceKey.cs,8020b477e70d8427). It's not affected by the environment

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ which means either the OP has an error, or some *other* brush uses a key that resolves to `ControlBrush`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, then if it's not affected by the environment, and no changes to the application/code what do you think the issue is?

Comment: As I said, some *other* resource has a key that resolves to the same value. Without the code though, it's just a guess. *Maybe* a *WPF* upgrade caused the change - Windows Update upgrades the .NET runtime binaries too, and .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ *maybe* that specific machine had a very old .NET version (4.0 perhaps?) and the upgrade introduced a newer version with breaking changes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos very well could be, nice thought, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: We have 2 persons that have experienced this, after their windows 7 pc's had an update and without any new release of the application. So it must be due to the windows 7 updates. This works perfectly well on windows 10 pc's.
Saying to a customers, sorry windows 7 reaches end of life in 2020, please update your pc, is out of the question.
I don't have the KB update id right now, however, it was a preview update.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the machines didn't have a very old version of .Net 4, but it doesn't matter, cause the code needs to be fixed so it can run anyway.
So do anyone have a suggestion to a work around, cause I guess I need to change the way the style is overriden.

Comment: @dennis_ler the error is clear - the same key was added twice. *That* line isn't at fault. That line returns the *correct* key. Something *else* in the same page returns the same key. It's impossible to guess what without that code. Post a complete example that actually reproduces the problem. You don't need to post a full application - just the container for the `<SolidColorBrush>` tag with enough code to reproduce the error, eg just the `<Page.Resources>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can this suddenly occur, when the code haven't changed the last month and been running fine ?
Furthermore, that specific code haven't changed for even longer and never had a problem. 
But it seems that where treeview style is overriden, the problem occurs for the windows7 machines now, after the update.

Comment: @dennis_ler This is a run time error or exception. It might possible that your `TreeView Resource SolidColorBrush` never executed so far and now it's executing and causing run time error/exception telling `SolidColorBrush key already exists`. I hope this will help you.

Comment: @dennis_ler that's a *Preview* .NET update, meant to allow people to test a future update and detect possible blocking issues - which I suspect, it did. You shouldn't install it in production.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that it is a preview update, but that is how microsoft test their updates rolling it out to pc's. It is not possible to configure in the WSUS server that client pc shouldn't get preview updates, I have talked with the IT department.
More specifically it is due to ndp48-kb4519568-x86_57739704597ae82f771152c084d756d2f187b13f.exe that is part of the update, removing this and installing ndp48-kb4515847-x86_3a86918366a8073eb9484c8c6f17a2b20b0088f6.exe instead solves the problem...

Comment: @dennis_ler they *don't*. They post them as *optional Preview* updates that people have to explicitly install so they can test *their code* before the preview is published, and decide whether they intend to deploy it once it's finalized.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes for people to select on the pc, if they do that manually. If using a WSUS server, it is apparently pushed out automatically. I haven't seen the WSUS configuration, but the IT guy, say that he CANNOT remove previes for client pc's only for servers.

Comment: @dennis_ler WSUS doesn't have such restrictions. It's the IT guy that should prevent that rollout by the way - just don't offer it to any client, server or not. Just block the package. `serverfault` is a better place for such questions.

Comment: @dennis_ler In any case, can you create a *minimal* example that reproduces the issue? This needs to be reported, but without an actual reproducible example, people won't be able to find out what's wrong. Even a simple ping on twitter would require *something* more concrete than "it breaks stuff"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kb4520406 update contains the package ndp48-kb4519568-x86_57739704597ae82f771152c084d756d2f187b13f.exe which is causing this issue, removing this and installing ndp48-kb4515847-x86_3a86918366a8073eb9484c8c6f17a2b20b0088f6.exe instead which isn't a preview solves the problem.

So I haven't tried to get solved buy code changes.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue in our application (ControlBrush added even though it is already there) after installing KB4519568. The interesting part is, our application is Wibu protected (dongle) and if I remove the Wibu protection the problem is gone. Do you use Wibu protection as well?

Comment: no, we don't use Wibu protection in the application

Comment: Yes, that might be the problem you see.